# What Polaroid instant film type is this?

Tags: film, polaroid

What Polaroid instant film type is the one on the right? (The left one is a Polaroid Type 600.)

[image: the samples in question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that Polaroid 600 is 3.1 inch by 3.1 inch, I deduce that film is 3.6 x 2.9 inch.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_film#Integral_film_2), Spectra / Image / 1200 cameras integral film is exactly that size.